# Move to top of page with chrome-extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

does anybody know a command to bind "scroll to top"/ "jump to top" function to a button?

I found something more fancy, but would like to have a more simple version:
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/chiikmhgllekggjhdfjhajkfdkcngplp

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can just do the following, scroll to X=0, and Y=0, and thats it https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.scroll

```
window.scroll(0, 0);
```

If you want to hook that up to Google Chrome Extensions, all you need to do is create a JavaScript file and inject it to your page:

**background.html**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'window.scroll(0, 0);'});
});
```

**manifest.json**

Make sure you have the tabs permission and browser action:

```
  ...
  ...
 "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "some_icon.png",
 },
 "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "http://*/*"
 ],
  ...
  ...
```

I havn't tested that, but it will give you an idea how to send a command from Chrome to Website through extensions via browser action button. Once you click on that button, it will execute a script to scroll that page to the top.absolute top.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Home</kbd>
(Simple, no over-thinking.)

Comment: @Conner it does answer the question

Answer (score 0):

To create an element with `id` "top" at the beginning of body, and assign the href of the "go to top" button to "#top", or add an event listener to it.

If you want it to show on the page persistently, use CSS rule `position: fixed` and appropriate other attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome extensions are html/js, right ? So just set the `scrollTop` attribute of `<body>` to `0`. Maybe there'is a more elegant way but this work :

```
<script>
function setScroll()
{
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop = 0;
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Set scrollTop to 50" onclick="setScroll();" />
```