# Google Chrome Extension Getting Started Tutorial not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to learn about google chrome extensions so from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4730746) I went to [this tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted).

I followed the instructions but both the [change of the page's color when clicking the button](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#logic) and the [options page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#options) don't work.

To make sure I didn't missed anything I downloaded the [completed extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/tutorials/get_started_complete.zip) but I got the same result.

Why does it not change the [page](https://developer.chrome.com/home)'s color when I click the button on the popup and when I go to the extension's options the page is blank? Is the tutorial obsolete/has something wrong in the code that wasn't updated? Can it be fixed/how?

The only related questions I have seen seem to be old when the example extension/tutorial was different.

Comment: The most important step you've missed is debugging. You really need it for extension development. Each part of an extension has its own method of invoking the devtools. See also the [updated demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug is tracked here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=827804

It seems that the scripts have some errors.
I have uploaded fixed scripts to the bugtracker.
You can try them.