# Building Spoiler Blocker chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

As a final project, I was asked to develop a chrome extension that Blocks movies/series Spoilers. I don't know where to start, couldn't find any helpful resource. 
I would like you to explain to me how these types of application work, where do I need to start, Does my application need a database?

I don't know if it's the right place to ask this kind of question or not, but I don't know another place to ask it so thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a spoiler blocker extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spoiler-protection-20/eelacikjiplnmdingehjfdjcfegclmkg

You can install that extension and see how it works, what is does, when you like to develop your own `spoiler blocker`.

I think you dont need any database.

**Hint:** Here is a good place to start with a chrome extension. See https://github.com/bfred-it/Awesome-WebExtensions

There are also good resources here in stackoverflow: see [Chrome Extension: How to create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725896/chrome-extension-how-to-create)

**Note:** could explain in detail what do you really want to do? Are you experienced in building a chrome-extension? When not follow the `Awesome-WebExtensions` link. When you have experience in building of a chrome extension then install the extension (see above) and look how it works and think about what how to split that extension in small pieces in order to find a start point.

Comment: Thank you so much. No i don't, It's my first time building a chrome extension

Comment: Look at here: https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples ! There are many examples how to do thinks with a extension. You have to have a strong will and hold on. No matter how long that takes :)